# How to get Text Content Pixel in Swing JButton

Tags: java, swing

As the title,I want to resize a JButton dynamicly by the Text Content on the button to make sure the Text is showing integrally under Multi-Language.But I don't know how to get the width  of the Text on JButton.

```
                 JButton btn = new JButton("Sure");
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to resize a JButton dynamicly by the Text Content on the button to make sure the Text is showing integrally under Multi-Language.But I don't know how to get the width of the Text on JButton.

You don't need to do this explicitly since the layout managers will take care of this for you if you're using them correctly. If you're adding JButtons to a GUI after the GUI has been rendered, then simply revalidate and repaint the container that is getting the button and the layout managers should do the rest.

Please note that if this advice doesn't help you, then perhaps there's more about your program and your problem that you need to tell us.

Comment: +1 for using Swing the way it was designed to be used by letting the layout manager do its job.

Comment: I test for this, you are right. It is because of in the controls Factory, there set PreferedSize for the Control,I should remove it.Thx for you help.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need the width of the text, you can get at it with:

```
int width = btn.getFontMetrics(btn.getFont()).stringWidth( "I want the width of this String" );
```

but unless you are doing something esoteric, as other posters point out, you probably don't actually need it.  Also note that (the width of the text) != (the width of the JButton), further making this answer useless!